# Plugin for changing page's title tag in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Right now, title tag on my site is "Blog post title - Blog site title". I want one page to have a custom title tag "Custom title tag", without "- Blog site title". But other pages should keep it, so I can't edit title tag format for every post.

Is there any plugin to easily do this?

P. S. By title tag, I mean `<title></title>`, not post headline.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the seo plugins give us the provision to change the title tag of certain pages, I recommend Yoast SEO plugin for that, just activate it and go to specific pages and you can see option named SEO Title, Just change it !!

Answer (score 0):

I want to change the website's individual blog title heading from h5 to h1.
I'm using this code for our website.
Individual blog page URL: https://stage1.veneratech.com/media-offline-what-is-it-and-how-to-deal-with-it

```
function change_all_post_titles_tag($title) {
// Replace <h2> tags with <h1> tags in the title
$title = str_replace('<h5>', '<h1>', $title);
$title = str_replace('</h5>', '</h1>', $title);

return $title;
```

}

// Hook the custom function to the_title filter
add_filter('the_title', 'change_all_post_titles_tag');